# Best performance in MS SQL - computed column with UDF vs trigger vs any other solution

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, calculated-columns

I am tasked with replacing duplicated text columns held in 40+ SQL tables with a lookup to a new table to hold a single set of data and reference this data by ID. The aim is to create a "single source of truth" and avoid multiple updates when a single record changes.

The db holds millions of rows in dozens of tables and these are accessed by hundreds of stored procs, views and functions etc. with a suite of web applications feeding and consuming the data. These in turn are accessed by 10,000+ users daily.

A rigorous solution would be to normalise the data and then rewrite all of the stored procs etc. to use the new structure. However the overhead on this is hundreds of hours of developer time.

I've investigated a shortcut of replacing the existing text columns with a computed column that references a UDF that returns the relevant text record. An example would look like...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [LookupMyText](@IDValue int)
    RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyReturn varchar(20)
    SELECT @MyReturn = R.MyTextField FROM dbo.MyLookupTable R WHERE R.UniqueID = @IDValue
    RETURN @MyReturn
END
```

And this would be referenced from the table definition along the lines of...

```
([dbo].[LookupMyText]([LookupID]))
```

However I'm reading that using a scalar UDF in a computed column causes a huge performance hit. Further, I cannot persist the column due to looking up user data.

So this looks like a non-starter.

Another solution might be to set a trigger on change for the new lookup table. Performance shouldn't be too bad as changes are infrequent (normally a few dozen a year, over 700 records or so).

Can anyone advise whether the above solutions are viable in your experience, or will I need to bite the bullet and go trawling through the stored procs etc. and do a proper normalisation job?

Comment: _"...and reference this data by ID"_ so do reference it in your `select` statements with `joins`.

Comment: Your are correct, a UDF in your scenario would have an awful impact on performance.  I don't think there is an easy way out for you on this one...